# how to implement a Simple "No Connection Toast ..." in CellPhone tracker app

Tags: android, gps, location, tracking

below i present the current code i have running, currently plain and simple.

yet , i would like to ***implement a toast that shows up when there is no GPS connection.***

it is the next step in my project so , i can't realy move on without it.

I have followed a few tutorials but they were in vain for a simple toast.

can anyone pls give me a simple example for this litlle problem ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView TxtLat;
    TextView TxtLong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TxtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtLat);
        TxtLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtLong);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new myLocationListener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    }
        class myLocationListener implements LocationListener
        {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
            {
                if (location != null)
                {
                    double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                    double pLat = location.getLatitude();

                    TxtLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
                    TxtLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Tnx ... it was a perfect answer to my question ! tnx

Answer (score 1):

Implement this way:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) youractivity.this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

  if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(youractivity.this, "You can improve the accuracy of your location by turning on: GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show(); 

  }else if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(youractivity.this, "You can improve the accuracy of your location by turning on: Wi-Fi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show(); 
 }else{

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(youractivity.this, "You can improve the accuracy of your location by turning on: GPS or Wi-Fi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }
```

And add below permission in your `manifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```